# RxJava, Room: Best way to update all the rows of Db using rxjava chain calls

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, android-room

I'm using rxjava & Room where I'm trying to update list of rows in db. 
Stuck in a loop where events are continuously firing

**Dao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM movies")
Flowable<List<Movie>> getMovies();

@Update
int updateMovie(Movie movie);
```

**UpdateClass** - helper classes is updating the Db like this

```
// Trying to get all existing movies and update one value in all of them.

@WorkerThread
Flowable<Integer> updateMovies(Helper help) {
    return movieDao.getMovies().flatMapIterable(movies -> movies)
        .flatMap(movie -> {
            LogUtils.debug("movieusecase", "movieid" + movie.getMovieId());
            movie.updateRating(help.getUpdatedVal(movie));
            return Flowable.just(movie);
        }).map(movie -> {
           return movieDao.updateMovie(movie);
        });
}
```

As soon as I include the `updateMovie` call I get stuck in an infinite loop where duplicate events keep on coming from room db.

**Presenter Class** - calls update class to update stuff in db. Gets triggered in activity `onCreate`

```
updateClass.updateMovies()
    .observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(movie -> {
        // update stuff
    }, throwable -> {
        LogUtils.error(TAG, throwable.getMessage());
    });
```

Thanks in advance any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a `Single` instead of a `Flowable`.

The difference is that `Single` will only fire once with the current list of movies in the DB, It will not keep emitting changes like `Flowable` does.

```
Single<List<Movie>> getMovies();
```

Or if you for some reason want your method to return `Flowable`, You can also use `Flowable.firstOrError()` which will transform your `Flowable` into a `Single` with a [cost](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#firstOrError--).

```
@WorkerThread
Flowable<Integer> updateMovies(Helper help) {
    return movieDao.getMovies()
        .firstOrError()
        .flatMapIterable(movies -> movies)
        .flatMap(movie -> { ... })
        .map(movie -> { ... });
}
```

I prefer the first option though for the sake of intention clarity.